# How to reset PC from FPGA (PCI board)

Tags: reset, fpga, pci

How to reset PC(motherboard) from FPGA on PCI board (without BIOS manipulations)
Subj.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not going to find a scheme that works with all motherboards, if you even find any.  Intel and AMD do this differently too.  If you're lucky to find a motherboard where the PCI reset signals are open drain you might be able to drive it and cause some bad stuff to happen and cause a reset.  If the motherboard drives those signals then you are out of luck (you could damage the driver).

You could also try to crash the system that would cause a reset, although that's getting harder nowadays with PCIe.  Operating systems seem to be able to survive bad PCI devices due to better error handling and timeouts, etc.

Is this to implement some sort of watchdog?  Probably easier to do this using IPMI and some sort of heart beat.